# Helm override only the key

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I want to override the key which is used in a helm chart prior to installing/upgrading.

For example, the default values.yaml given in a chart is as follows, but I wish to rename "influx" to "influxdb". Is there a helm --set command I can run to do that?

```
service:
  annotations: {}
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 9000
  expose:
    postgresql:
      enabled: false
      port: 8812
    influx:
      enabled: false
      port: 9009
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it with helm.

You can write a script to do it but I can't think of a reason for it if you change the key you will also need to change it in the helm template for it you need the entire chart code.